# Building an SSIS EXPRESSION to test if a variable contain a value or specific string

Tags: ssis

I would like to not execute the package if the value of the variable is null or equal to the number zero or to the string 'none'

!ISNULL(@[User::MaxRef])  &&  @[User::MaxRef] > 0

!ISNULL(@[User::MaxRef]) <--- this is correct 
but for others how should I continue?

thank you

Comment: others?   other whats?   I have no idea what you're trying to ask.   Add a lot more detail.

Comment: || = or is SSIS

Comment: https://snag.gy/tf9n1B.jpg

Comment: thank you KeithL :) my solution is @[User::MaxRef]  != "0" because in my case zero is a string